# Will resetting Windows 8 affect recovery partition?

Tags: windows-8, recovery-partition

Recently I have bought a second hand HP Notebook from a friend.

The PC still has the recovery partition not backed up yet. However, I'm thinking of resetting Windows using the new Windows 8 resetting feature.

Windows warned me that all files will be deleted.

Is it okay to reset Windows then backup the recovery partition in order to have a fresh backup or this can lead to losing the recovery partition and, with it, my genuine copy of Windows 8?

Comment: The feature only modifies the Windows partition

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ramhound said, resetting Windows this way will only affect your Windows partitions. No other partitions will be affected in this process.